# Power BI - Value increases 3 days or more in a row

Tags: formatting, powerbi, conditional-statements, dax

Hi I am wanting to have a RAG trigger for if a value has increased 3 days in a row or 5 days in a row.

For example if the value increases 3 days in a row.

```
26/07   1
27/07   5
28/07   12
```

I would want the value colour to turn amber

and if it increases 5 days or more in a row I would want the colour to be red.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the nicest solution but that is a start.

At first, you will need to create a measure to return the colour based on your condition. Something like that:

```
Measure =
VAR PreviousDayValue =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Dataset[Value] ),
        DATEADD ( Dataset[Date], -1, DAY )
    )
VAR TwoDaysAgoValue =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Dataset[Value] ),
        DATEADD ( Dataset[Date], -2, DAY )
    )
VAR ThreeDaysAgoValue =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Dataset[Value] ),
        DATEADD ( Dataset[Date], -3, DAY )
    )
VAR FourDaysAgoValue =
    CALCULATE (
        MIN ( Dataset[Value] ),
        DATEADD ( Dataset[Date], -4, DAY )
    )
RETURN
    IF (
        MIN ( Dataset[Value] ) > PreviousDayValue
            && PreviousDayValue > TwoDaysAgoValue
            && TwoDaysAgoValue > ThreeDaysAgoValue
            && ThreeDaysAgoValue > FourDaysAgoValue,
        2,
        IF (
            MIN ( Dataset[Value] ) > PreviousDayValue
                && PreviousDayValue > TwoDaysAgoValue
                && TwoDaysAgoValue > ThreeDaysAgoValue,
            1,
            BLANK ()
        )
    )
```

And then you can setup conditional formatting for your [Value] column using "Format by rules" option:

[image: format by rules window]

After that, it will look like that:

[image: final table view]

The fourth row was also formatted as red here, but you can change it to amber simply switching conditions in the measure formula.